# Is it possible to load + render an html.erb file within another html.erb file?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible to render another file, such as my show.html.erb, within my main.html.erb file?

"show.html.erb" belongs to a calendar controller.  "main.html.erb" belongs to a Pages controller.

I want to do this because:

1. I need to access some specific data from within the calendar in the database.
2. I don't want my calendar to take up an entire view frame. I want it to be small and be integrated into the main page.

How would I go about doing this? Is it a silly idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, with [partials](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html). So if you want to render `_my_view.html.erb` within some other view, you should insert the following:

```
<%= render partial: "my_view", locals: { myvar: @val } %>
```

Where you can pass variables to the partial through the `locals` hash.

Comment: where would I handle this partial for CSS?

Comment: @Sarahshuffle What do you mean? CSS is handled by the asset pipeline. You can also load it directly in the html file.

Comment: don't worry it was a silly question, I just realised I could put a div round it and control how it looked from css :)